# Resolving an open generic type with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have the following piece of code

```
public void Test()  
{
   // Configure DI
   IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

   services.AddTransient<IEngine<MetaData>, myEngine>(); 
   // Tried
   // services.AddTransient(typeof(IEngine<>), typeof(Engine<MetaData>));

   var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

   // Request Instance from DI, at this point I dont want to have to that 
   // tell it I want and Engine with a MetaData
   var engine1 = provider.GetRequiredService<IEngine<MetaData>>();
}
```

My classes look like

```
public class MyEngine : IEngine<MetaData>
{
    public IReader<MetaData> Reader { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Engine<T> : IEngine<T>
{
    public IReader<T> Reader { get; set; }

    public Engine(IReader<T> reader)
    {
        Reader = reader;
    }
}

public interface IReader<T>
{
    T MetaData { get; set; }
}

public interface IEngine<T>
{
    IReader<T> Reader { get;set;}

}
```

I would prefer to have something like this code as I don't care what `T` is

```
var engine2 = provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(IEngine<>));
```

Comment: That's not really how generics work.  If you don't care about T, then have your IEngine<T> implement a non-generic version of the interface called IEngine.

Comment: I care about T in my implementation but not when I create the Instances. When I configure DI I want to tell it what T is but when I ask for an IEngine I don't want to tell it what T is. The method in my example is just to show this working, in the app the DI is setup in StartUp and I just want to ask for an IEngine I dont care what the concrete class is. Thanks

Comment: Generics are compile-time types or compiled types. If you want to determine types and respective objects at runtime, perhaps make IEngine/IReader depend on Object type and fill that up later; since you won't be calling your DI container again to fill Engine up (as partial object construction).

Comment: You may use factory method pattern and inject that via your DI to Engine and then pass newly determined type at runtime to your factory method; but still that won't be generic though dynamically created. (Not DLR)

Comment: I did think of using a factory, I may give that ago. T is used to hold data, its read by the reader and it is stored by a class not shown in my mini version.

Comment: I missed a class, sorry, code updated.. I do think this can be done with DI.. but I will look at going via a factory